# Android-like design pattern for websites

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, html, xaml

Is there a design pattern out there that is similar to Android's structure, but for websites?

What I love about it is design and code are completely separate. Designers design and coders make the design come to life. Designers don't need to know database or model or any form of underlying data.

I've tried [ASP.NET MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC) 4 [Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor) which felt like stepping back decades. Some design is separate, but to make it all work, you seem to have to ask coders to inject design with model knowledge blindfold, only knowing if it works or looks correct after running it. It felt like I may as well be using [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29).

Is there a technology out there, like Android, but for Windows website development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for any [model–view–controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) PHP framework.

[Symfony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) is heavy gear, so if you would feel overwhelmed, try [CodeIgniter_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeIgniter) or [Yii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii). There are frameworks for other languages as well: Ruby ([Ruby on Rails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails)), Python ([Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)), etc.